# Internet Explorer crashes when opening large complex silverlight diagram

Tags: internet-explorer, silverlight

I am working on a silverlight application. When opening a large, complex silverlight object internet explorer crashes on most machines.
On few desktops, laptops we are able to open page and we have noticed that memory being consumed by browser is in range of 1.4+ GB and on machines where it is failing for browser memory usage is somehow getting limited to approx 1.2 GB.

How can we remove limit on memory which browser can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to resolve it, needed to increase maximum memory which can be allocated to a process